# Como criar gráfico de barras usando DataFrame.plot?

Tags: python, dataframe, plot

Estou tentando fazer um gráfico de uma tabela comparando a taxa de homens não alfabetizados com a taxa de mulheres não alfabetizadas. Tenho um arquivo csv com esses dados e estou tentando colocar os homens e as mulheres na linha "x" e a quantidade de pessoas não alfabetizadas na linha "y", até agora meu código está assim:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1k_kvlZ6zpnMeHUoA7GCEoMkKc7ybQLCX", sep=';' , encoding='latin-1')
df["qnthomens"] = df["HomensNaoAlfabetRural"] + df["HomensNaoAlfabetUrb"]
df["qntmulheres"] = df["MulheresNaoAlfabetRural"] + df["MulheresNaoAlfabetUrb"]
quantidade = df["qntmulheres"] and df["qnthomens"]
df["quantidade"] = quantidade
sexo = ['Homens', 'Mulheres']
df["sexo"] = sexo


plt.title('Homens x Mulheres')
df.plot(kind='bar',x='sexo',y='quantidade')
plt.show()
```

Estou tentando criar uma coluna "quantidade" e colocar dois valores diferentes dentro dela, a soma dos homens não alfabetizados de área urbana e rural, e também a soma das mulheres não alfabetizadas das mesmas áreas

Já na coluna "sexo" que eu criei eu inseri "homens" e "mulheres" para ficar na linha "x" do gráfico, porém me reportam o erro

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Já tentei de diversas formas e não faço ideia do que fazer, sou novo nisso e não acho nada na internet...

Comment: Acho que você não precisa de utilizar o plot do dataframe nesse caso. Note que vc não precisa da coluna inteira, apenas da soma de cada uma. By the way: o erro tá sendo provocado pela linha `quantidade = df["qntmulheres"] and df["qnthomens"]`. A expressão lógica deveria ser feita elementwise, mas minha aposta é que não é isso que vc quer fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi bem o que você quer fazer, não precisa do `DataFrame.plot`. É mais simples que isso:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("tabela_trabalho2.csv", sep=';' , encoding='latin-1')
df["qnthomens"] = df["HomensNaoAlfabetRural"] + df["HomensNaoAlfabetUrb"]
df["qntmulheres"] = df["MulheresNaoAlfabetRural"] + df["MulheresNaoAlfabetUrb"]

x=[1,2]
plt.title('Homens x Mulheres')
plt.bar(x,height=[df["qnthomens"].sum(),df["qntmulheres"].sum()] )
plt.xticks(x, ('Homens','Mulheres'))
plt.show()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A implementação do gráfico de barras com `matplotlib` diretamente tem o benefício de ser mais simples. De acordo com a [documentação](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html), o `plt.bar` precisa apenas de uma sequência de escalares (que você pode renomear posteriormente) e uma lista com as alturas das barras.